# Issues on Navigation bar- toggle bar when clicked doesn't show the pages

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav, togglebutton

I have followed the instruction on the navbar,but when the toggle button is clicked it doesn't show the pages.What could be the issue?I am working on windows 10.
Here below is the HTML code.

```html
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm  fixed-top ">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Ristorante con Fusion</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
        </div>

         
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need remove the `.navbar-toggler` from the button since by default its using `display:none;`

Then you also need to remove `.navbar-collapse` from the #Navbar since its forcing the item to be visible with `display: flex !important`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm  fixed-top ">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            Text
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Ristorante con Fusion</a>
        <div class="collapse" id="Navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Double check if you added the jQuery library and Bootstrap Js. if not, you can refer to the links below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I  want .navbar-toggler and navbar-collapse for making the items to be hidden on small screen and .If I remove I am loosing the items for large screen sizes.

Comment: You mean, you only want the button and navbar to appear on desktop and hide on mobile right?

Comment: @PetrosBelachew - did you add the jquery and bootstrap js? i tried your code and its working when i resize to smaller screen.

On Desktop, only the Ristorante text and menu is visible. Then if you resize on mobile, the button will show and the menu will be hidden. When you click the button it will show the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you.popper.min.js file was unfortunately removed from the folder.And after adding it my issue was solved.

Comment: @PetrosBelachew - great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in `<button>` tag

```
onclick="document.location='link.html'"
```

(link.html) should be any page that you want to open

Comment: The toggle button has to show the items,but it doesn't work.I have tried and it refreshes the specific page.I want to show me the different items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the site you want to visit to the href.
Simply replace the # with the link of your site.
You also dont need the ./ in front of your html document if it is in the same Folder as the index.html

```html
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm  fixed-top ">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="ristorante.html">Ristorante con Fusion</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
        </div>

         
    </nav>
```

Comment: I have tried.But,the problem is with showing the menu items(pages) not the specific page.The toggle button doesn't show the items.

Comment: So you want to display the items when the button Ristorante con Fusion is clicked?

Comment: No.I want to display the items when the toggle button is clicked on small screen sizes.